# Is it possible to create a key on a different frame?

Tags: animation

Odd question perhaps: but is it possible while on -let's say, frame 25- to create a key with current location values NOT on frame 25, but on frame 50 ?

If a later frame has keyed location data for example, moving the playhead to frame 50 changes the location data before I can key the position it has at 25.

That must sound really odd, but I've recently transitioned from Maya and that facility is there in multiple ways. (middle mouse drag timeline, or even set key at x frame via menu etc).  I realise I can make a key at current frame, cut the keys, move to frame x and paste the keys, but that's not exactly fluid.

Comment: You can create a keyframe then move it in the timeline.

Comment: Thank you.  And yes that is an option (though still a little cumbersome when doing it repeatedly across thousands of frames).  I was rather hoping there was a numeric @Frame X  option I was missing

Comment: you can press G 50 after creating the keyframes to move selected ones 50 frames in time... so if it is relative time is not that difficult, be sure to keep mouse over animation editor... other trick is Shift+R to repeat, so you move 10 frames with G 10, press Shift+R to move 10 frames farther in time and so on

Comment: alambre, thank you.  That's a fantastic tip.  Not quite what I was looking for, but a *great* tip :)

Comment: if you press `i` you can add a keyframe on current frame, so just move the slider or type in the frame you want and press i and click on location